# Compare two nested json files and show user where exactly the change has occurred and which json file using Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have two json files. I am validating the response is same or different. I need to show the user where there is an exact change. Some what like the particular key is added or removed or changed in this file.

file1.json

```
[
{
  "Name": "Jack",
  "region": "USA",
  "tags": [
     {
        "name": "Name",
        "value": "Assistant"
     }
   ]
 },
  {
  "Name": "MATHEW",
  "region": "USA",
  "tags": [
     {
        "name": "Name",
        "value": "Worker"
      }
   ]
  }
]
```

file2.json

```
    [
{
  "Name": "Jack",
  "region": "USA",
  "tags": [
     {
        "name": "Name",
        "value": "Manager"
     }
   ]
 },
  {
  "Name": "MATHEW",
  "region": "US",
  "tags": [
     {
        "name": "Name",
        "value": "Assistant"
      }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

If you see Two JSON you can find the difference as a region in file2.json has changed US and Values changed from manager to assistant and worker. Now I want to show the user that file2.json has some changes like region :US and Manager changed to Assistant.

I have used deepdiff for validating purpose.

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

def difference(oldurl_resp,newurl_resp,file1):
    ddiff = DeepDiff(oldurl_resp, newurl_resp,ignore_order=True)

     if(ddiff == {}):

        print("BOTH JSON FILES MATCH !!!")
        return True

    else:
       print("FAILURE")

       output = ddiff
       if(output.keys().__contains__('iterable_item_added')):
         test = output.get('iterable_item_added')
         print('The Resource name are->')
         i=[]
         for k in test:
            print("Name: ",test[k]['Name'])
            print("Region: ",test[k]['region'])
            msg= (" Name ->"+ test[k]['Name'] +" Region:"+test[k]['region'] +".  ")

            i.append(msg)


           raise JsonCompareError("The json file has KEYS changed!. Please validate  for below" +str(i) +"in "+file1)

    elif(output.keys().__contains__('iterable_item_removed')):
        test2 = output.get('iterable_item_removed')
        print('The name are->')
        i=[]
        for k in test2:
            print(test2[k]['Name'])
            print(test2[k]['region'])
            msg= (" Resource Name ->"+ test2[k]['Name'] +" Region:"+test2[k]['region'] +".  ")

            i.append(msg)


        raise JsonCompareError("The json file has Keys Removed!!. Please validate for below" +str(i)+"in "+file1)
```

This code just shows the resource Name I want to show the tags also which got changed and added or removed.
Can anybody guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just print out the values of "test" variables, you will find out that "tag" variable changes are inside of it, test value of test in this example will be:

```
test = {'root[0]': {'region': 'USA', 'Name': 'Jack', 'tags': [{'name': 'Name', 'value': 'Manager'}]}, 'root[1]': {'region': 'US', 'Name': 'MATHEW', 'tags': [{'name': 'Name', 'value': 'Assistant'}]}}
```

and you can print `test[k]['tags']` or add it your "msg" variable.

**Suggestion:**

Also, if your data has some primary key (for example they have "id", or their order is always fixed), you can compare their data 1 by 1 (instead of comparing whole lists) and you can have a better comparison. For example if you compare data of "Jack" together, you will have the following comparison:

```
{'iterable_item_removed': {"root['tags'][0]": {'name': 'Name', 'value': 'Assistant'}}, 'iterable_item_added': {"root['tags'][0]": {'name': 'Name', 'value': 'Manager'}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try the [deepdiff](https://deepdiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. It gives you the key where the difference occurs and the old and new value.

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
ddiff = DeepDiff(json_object1, json_object2)

# if you want to compare by ignoring order
ddiff = DeepDiff(json_object1, json_object2, ignore_order=True)
```